# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - Ionic2

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

my project is working fine until ytd. I am not sure why, when I “ionic serve” the project, this error keeps prompting.

Ionic Serve Error Message
[image: Ionic Serve Error Message]

And I went to check my build folder in WWW, all the files are gone except these.

Build Folder files
[image: Build Folder files]

I have already tried the below methods but all doesn’t work for me:

1. Create a new project and put in my files.
2. npm install
3. npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
4. npm install -g ionic cordova

Any idea, what I can do to install back my build folder files?

Comment: how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I had when one of the plugin in "plugin.xml" file had wrong path. Wrong:

```
<config-file target="app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
```

Good:

```
<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solved it by just **clearing the browser data/history**. ***NOTE that I'am using v4. beta ionic***
I hope that helps!

Comment: i have cleared my browser data and history thrice but does not work still for ionic 4 version.

Answer (score 0):

clear the cache of the browser whenever the new version of ionic lab is installed.