# Ionic App - Cordova build - Intel XDK - Showing white screen after splash

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having problem in resolving the white screen in the ionic mobile app.

**I followed the below steps:**

1. Ionic Start
2. Project Name: Test
3. Framework: Angular
4. Starter template : conference   | A kitchen-sink application that shows off all Ionic has to offer
5. Ionic Serve : This is executing successfully and app is successfully in browser
6. Build the cordova app to create www folder:
   ionic cordova prepare android
   ionic build cordova
7. This creates the www folder
8. Then i am using Intel XDK tool : To create the package
9. Then i am using https://build.phonegap.com/ to create the .apk
10. .apk is successfully created
11. Once i install the app in android mobile phone : App is opening and splash screen is shown successfully
    12: But the issue is after splash screen, i am seeing white screen and nothing is happening after that
12. My config.xml has below info:
13. The same config file if used in ionic 2, it is working fine.
    Please help.

Config.XML Message is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android-versionCode="1" version="0.0.1" id="com.test.game"  >

<!-- This file was generated by the Intel XDK Cordova Package Build tool. -->

<name>Game</name>

<description>Play game in your mobile phone</description>

<author></author>

<content src="index.html"/>

<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />

<platform name="android" >

    <access origin="*"/>

</platform>

<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#fa8039" />

<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />

<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.2"/>

<plugin name="es6-promise-plugin" spec="4.2.2"/>

<plugin name="cordova-admob-sdk" spec="0.20.2"/>

<plugin name="cordova-connectivity-monitor" spec="1.2.2"/>

<plugin name="cordova-google-play-services" spec="25.0.0"/>

<plugin name="cordova-libgoogleadmobads" spec="https://github.com/appfeel/google-iosadmobads#master"/> <!-- If available via Cordova registry; consider changing to an NPM reference. -->

<plugin name="phonegap-admob" spec="4.2.1"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.0.12"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.4.0"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-market" spec="1.2.0"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2"/>

<preference  name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>

<preference  name="UIwebviewbounce" value="false"/>

<preference  name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>

<platform name="android" >

    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>

    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29"/>

    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>

    <preference name="android-signed" value="true"/>

    <preference name="Orientation" value="default"/>

    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>

    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>

</platform>

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/3204261.png" density="ldpi" width="320" height="426" orientation="portrait"/>

<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/3204701.png" density="mdpi" width="320" height="470" orientation="portrait"/>

<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/4806401.png" density="hdpi" width="480" height="640" orientation="portrait"/>

<splash platform="android" src="package-assets/7209601.png" density="xhdpi" width="720" height="960" orientation="portrait"/>

<icon platform="android" src="package-assets/36AS.png" density="ldpi" width="36" height="36"/>

<icon platform="android" src="package-assets/48AS.png" density="mdpi" width="48" height="48"/>

<icon platform="android" src="package-assets/72AS.png" density="hdpi" width="72" height="72"/>

<icon platform="android" src="package-assets/96AS.png" density="xhdpi" width="96" height="96"/>

<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application" mode="merge"> 

    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" />

</config-file>

</widget>
```

Below is the chrome->console error. I am not able to resolve this warning.
[Chrome->Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blGxO.png)

Below is the error i am getting now after running command:
ionic cordova platform add browser
ionic cordova run browser

[chrome->console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tftcK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:In config.xml, verify your existing information and provide the below only:

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

Step 2: In app.component.ts, update the below:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      }, 1000);

    });
  }
```

This should resolve the issue. The Splash will remain active and spinner will also remain active till the homepage is displayed. There won't be any white screen after splash.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it from android studio bottom bar run, logcat, build etc..
[image]

Other hand you can debug it from google chrome just type: `chrome://inspect`
and you can see the following:
(if your app is running in android studio emulator or connected phone)

[image]

You should click on inspect and will see something like this:

[image]

Here on console tab you can check what causes the white screen error.

Comment: I have included the chrome->console error. But not able to resolve the error. i have included the cordova plugin for both splash and status bar. As i mentioned, the app is working for ionic 2 but for latest ionic build it is showing white screen after splash.

Comment: 404 (Not Found). So something is missing. If you click on manifest.json will it show something?

Comment: Or you can try to `cordova platform remove android` and after `cordova platform add android`

Comment: I tried these 2 commands, but still getting one error. I have added the image. cordova platform add browser/
ionic cordova run browser

Comment: Manifest.json file is as below: {
  "name": "Ionic Conference",
  "short_name": "Ionic Conference",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/img/appicon.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "background_color": "#387ef5",
  "theme_color": "#387ef5"
}

Comment: I have found this: `<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">` if the path is correct..

Comment: Where to check this path? <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">

Comment: Any suggestion? I am still stuck with my project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282083/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found/

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz example?